# If statement inside while loop not giving accurate result. PHP MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query that is querying  two fields. The first field is the date and the second is the code related to that date. Im trying to develop an IF statement which looks at the code and determines whether its DOT or NO DOT. The problem im having is that the code is skipping the IF statement even though its true. I know for a fact 'PO' is the name of that specific code. Any suggestions would awesome. Here is the code:

```
if ($row_count1 < 9 and $row_count2 < 12 ){
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial',b,14);
  $pdf->SetXY(66,165);
  $pdf->Cell(70,5,"Drug / Alcohol Information ",0);

  $pdf->SetFont('Arial',B,8);
  $pdf->SetXY(49,172);
  $sql6 = ("SELECT ua_detail,da_code
            FROM ua_detail WHERE ua_detail.driver_code = '$searchTerm'" );
  $result=mysql_query($sql6)or die ('query did not run');
  $row_count = mysql_num_rows( $result );
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result))
  { 
    if ($row[0] > 0 ){      
      $ddate =  substr($row['ua_detail'],0,2).$slash.substr($row['ua_detail'],2,2).$slash.substr($row['ua_detail'],4,4);
      $code =  $row ['da_code'];    
      if ( $code == 'PO'){
        $DOT = "DOT Positive";
      } 
      else if ( $code != 'PO') {
        $DOT = "Non DOT Positive";
      } 
      $pdf->Cell(70,3,"Date Of Failure:"."  ".$ddate.   "        Test Code : "  . $code.    "      DOT / NON DOT: "     .$DOT,0);
    }
    else{
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial',B,10);
      $pdf->SetXY(68,172);
      $pdf->Cell(70,5,"No Failed or refused UA on record",0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think we have enough info here - how do you know the if statement is getting skipped?

Comment: Just to be clear, if you do `var_dump($code);` do you get `string(2) "PO"`?

Comment: yes, I do get PO which is the result of 'test code'

Comment: @jay its getting skipped because I $code = 'PO' and $DOT is still displaying  'NON DOT' which is not correct

Comment: We would have to see where the data is coming from then - the if is working ok, just the data being delivered is not if I understand you correctly.

Comment: This chunk of code  is inside of a while loop which queries the database. All of the data queried is correct and giving the accurate results but when i try to define $DOT based on the $code result, it gives me the 'else' statement even though $code = 'PO'

Comment: If you are not hitting `$DOT = "DOT Positive"`, then `$code` **does not equal** "PO".  It can't. PHP isn't arbitrarily going to decide not to follow it's own logic. You need to check for white spaces, capitalization differences, etc.

Comment: I know Robbert and I agree 100%. Thats why im asking on here because its just not making sense. I have checked and triple checked.

Comment: I got it! The structure of the column in mysql was setup as a varchar 4 instead of 2 which in turn made the comparison in adequate. I fixed the structure to a varcher 2 and it works great. Thanks for all the help troubleshooting. I really do appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this block of code

```
$code =  $row ['da_code'];    
if ( $code == 'PO'){
  $DOT = "DOT Positive";
} 
else if ( $code != 'PO') {
  $DOT = "Non DOT Positive";
}
```

always results in "Non DOT Positive", then $code does not equal "PO".  You need to look at the value of $code to be sure. Remember PHP is case sensitive, meaning "po" is not the same as "PO".  Also, check for white spaces.  One way to check for white space is to echo $code with quotes like this

```
 echo '"' . $code . '"';
```

If you don't see white spaces, make sure there's no newline character by looking at the source code. If you see the ending quote on a different line, then you'll know there's linebreak in `$code`.

Also, your `else if` statement is redudant. You can just write it as else

```
$code =  $row ['da_code'];    
if ( $code == 'PO'){
  $DOT = "DOT Positive";
} 
else{
  $DOT = "Non DOT Positive";
}
```

And finally, don't use mysql_* functions. They are deprecated. You should use PDO or mysqli.